# Connection timeout VS IIS

Tags: c#, mysql

I get this exception in my error log..

> The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   obtaining a connection from the pool.

Restarting the IIS makes me to login back to my app.. so where do you think the issue is? Is it in IIS property setting?

Code is something like this:

```
MySqlConnection connection = null;
try
{
    connection = MySqlConnectionHandler.OpenConnection();
    string strText =string.Empty;
    strText = "<<sql statement>>";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strText, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("ID", MySqlDbType.Int32));
        cmd.Parameters["ID"].Value = 100;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
finally
{
    MySqlConnectionHandler.CloseConnection(connection);
}
```

My CloseConnection method internally has

```
if (con != null)
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/kk-KZ/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/c57c0432-c27b-45ab-81ca-b2df76c911ef

Comment: @Brad - just to add, the accepted answer there makes some odd claims about calling `Close()` instead of just `Dispose()`; this is unnecessary - `Dispose()` calls `Close()`

Answer (score 2):

That almost always means you aren't calling `Dispose()` on your connections, and you have saturated the pool until GC runs - which it probably won't if your app is now dead. Essentially, you have opened connections successively over a period of time (without ever giving them back), and now there are none left. Solution: give them back to the pool when you are done.

Whenever you use something like a connection, use a `using` statement, or some other mechanism to ensure it is disposed promptly when you are done with it. The same applies to anything `IDisposable`, but connections are particularly vulnerable to this.

Comment: Thanks but i do call Dispose(), edited with my sample code, pls. throw your inputs.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 on all calls, religiously? There aren't *any, anywhere* that are missed?

Comment: using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
                        while(reader.Read())
                        {
                           //some statements
                        }
  }


Does this looks okay or it should be like this?

  using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
                        while(reader.Read())
                        {
                           //some statements
                        }
                        reader.Close(); 
  }

Comment: @Sharpeye500 in almost cases, `Dispose()` calls `Close()`, so if you are `using` you *rarely* need `Close()`, however... ;p

Comment: @ Marc - May be not :) or else  i might have got this error,which i didn't...

"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first"

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you do call Dispose()...

I would try two things. *Temporarily* increase your connection timeout to see if that's the issue:

```
MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 45; //in seconds
```

This will slow your application so you should only use it for troubleshooting. If it is you need to optimize your SQL query.

Alternately, your [connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) may be exceeded, so you may need to bump that up.